# Allow access to Apache on both port 80 and 443 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, ufw

I've just installed UFW 0.35 on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
root@localhost:/etc# ufw --version
ufw 0.35
Copyright 2008-2015 Canonical Ltd.
```

and

```
root@localhost:/etc# ufw app list
Available applications:
  OpenSSH
```

I would like to allow access to Apache on both port 80 and 443, with the command

```
$ ufw allow "Apache Full"
```

but I got an error

```
ERROR: Could not find a profile matching 'Apache Full'
```

Comment: `ufw allow http` and `ufw allow https` work for me.  You can also just specify the ports  - `ufw allow 80` and `ufw allow 443` - the "service names" or "profiles" are there for convenience, and simply specify default port numbers.

Comment: @ivanivan:  That looks like an answer.  Please post answers *as answers*, not as comments.

Comment: @G-Man possible, but it felt more comment-ish when I typed it.

Comment: the profile is created by apache after its installation, so its better to install the firewall after the apache, then the profile is available

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are likely receiving that error because there has not been a profile created for 'Apache Full'.  You can see which profiles exist on your system by checking the directory:

```
/etc/ufw/applications.d/
```

To create a profile known as 'Apache Full' create a file in the above directory using the following syntax (from the man page):

```
     [Apache Full]
     title=<title>
     description=<description>
     ports=80/tcp,443/tcp
```

Next, you will update ufw app:

```
ufw app update "Apache Full"
```

Now you should be able to run the command from your question:

```
ufw allow "Apache Full"
```

To confirm that your profile is included in ufw's rules run:

```
ufw status
```

Comment: What is the type of the file?

Comment: I'm not sure which file you're asking about but the application profiles are stored in a plain text, flat file in the `/etc/ufw/applications.d/` directory.

Comment: Didn't quite work for me on Debian 10.3! I had to replace the last line by ports=80/tcp|443/tcp

Comment: Could be all on `/etc/ufw/applications.d/apache2-utils.ufw.profile`. Try better with `sudo ufw app list`, then for eg `sudo ufw app info Apache Secure`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

> ufw allow "Apache Full"

you should use,

> ufw allow "WWW Full"

You have to look in your /etc/ufw/applications.d/ dictionary which file is available. Maybe it is called "Http Full".

Comment: I use Lubuntu 20_04 and I have `WWW
  WWW Cache
  WWW Full
  WWW Secure`: After ufw allow "WWW Full" and ufw status I get an inactive status.